# Model underfitting

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I have trained a model and it took me quite a while to find the correct hyperparameters.
The model has now been trained for 15h and it seems to to its job quite well.

When I observed the training and validation loss though, the training loss is somewhat higher than the validation loss. (red curve: training, green: validation)

[image]

I use dropout to regularize my model and as far as I have understood, droput is is only applied during training which might be the reason.

Now Iam wondering if I have trained a valid model? 
It doesn't seem like the model is heavily underfitted?

Thanks in advance for any advice,

cheers,

M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check whether you have good data set, i.e., if it is a classification, then get equal number of images for all classes and get it from same source not from different sources. And regularization, dropout are used for overfitting/High variance so don't worry about these.

Then, I think your model is doing good when you trained your model the initial error between them are different but as you increased the epochs then they both got into some steady path. So it is good. And may be reason for this is as I mentioned above or you should try shuffle them then using train_test_split for getting better distribution of training and validation sets.
A plot of learning curves shows a good fit if:

1. The plot of training loss decreases to a point of stability.
2. The plot of validation loss decreases to a point of stability and has a small gap with the training loss.

In your case these conditions are satisfied.

Still if you want to deal with High Bias/underfitting then here are few methods:

1. Train bigger models
2. Train longer. Use better optimization techniques
3. Try different Neural Network Architecture and also hyper parameters

And also you can use cross-validation or GridSearchCV for finding better optimizer or hyper parameters but it may take really long because you have to train it on different parameters each time considering your time which is 15 hours then it might be very long but you will find better parameters and then train on it.

Above all I think your model is doing okay.

Comment: Hi an thanks for your comments. I continued training for an additional 200 epochs and the training loss keeps decreasing while the validation loss is constant. So I guess I just have to keep on training until convergence. I even tried a somewhat higher learning rate, but training does not work that well as before.

Comment: In your question the what makes you to think that this model is not valid. What I am trying to say is your learning curve is good. And according to graph what I think is may be the data set you split, from validation set the algorithm is not learning i.e., unable to find all required features in validation set that is the reason there is disturbance in learning curve for validation. So, try on the data set shuffle or split correctly. And also try different methods I mentioned not only learning_rate. Hope this helps. Feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If your model **underfits**, its performance will be lower, similar as in the case of **overfitting**, because actually it can not learn effectively to get the optimal result, i.e the proper function to fit the given distribution. So you have to use less regularization technique e.g. less dropout to get the optimal result.

Furthermore the **sampling** can also be crucial, because there can be training-validation subsets where your model performs well on validation set and less effective on training set and vice-versa. This is one of the reason why we use **crossvalidation** and different sampling methods e.g. **stratified k-fold**.